# Making a Confirmation in Electron.js

Tags: node.js, electron, dialog

I want to make a message box which contains yes and no buttons in a electron.js app. I tried to do it with [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog) inside the electron. But it didn't work:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { dialog } = electron
console.log(dialog) // undefined
```

```
const electron = require('electron')
const dialog = electron.remote.dialog
console.log(dialog) // Uncaught Error: Cannot read "dialog" of undefined (remote is undefined)
```

Then, I tried to do it with [dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialog) which is a module in npm. But it didn't do the thing that I want to do. There wasn't any yes or no buttons also it returned the same responses when I clicked OK or I closed window:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const dialog = require('dialog')
dialog.info('Are you sure?', 'Confirmation', function(exitCode) {
        if (exitCode == 0) {
                // Should clicked OK (always response)
        }
        if (exitCode == 1) {
                // Should closed window (but never works)
        }
})
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're trying to do this from the renderer process, right? If so, what is your Electron version? Do you have `nodeIntegration` enabled on the `BrowserWindow` in question?

Comment: @Alexander Leithner yes, my electron version is 15.1.2 and i have enabled nodeIntegration.

Comment: When is your dialog generated? After clicking a button / link in your render process or mid-action in your main process? Additionally, being a yes / no dialog, would either response perform a particular action? Depending on the answers depends on how it could be implemented.

Comment: @midnight-coding This function is called when a **button is clicked in a render process** And "yes" response performs an action. However, "No" response triggers nothing in my code

Comment: Does the action happen in the main process or the render process?

Comment: in the render process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use
Electron's [`dialog.showMessageBox();`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options)
method.

> The [dialog.showMessageBoxSync();](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxsyncbrowserwindow-options)
> method would block your main process until a response is received, so you won't want to use that unless intended.

---

I have placed the creation and management of your dialog box in the `main.js` file. If you want to move this into its
own file, that's not a problem. All you would need to do is `get()` the (main) window instance if you want your dialog
box to be a child of the main window.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required Electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('openDialog', () => {
    electronDialog.showMessageBox(window, {
        'type': 'question',
        'title': 'Confirmation',
        'message': "Are you sure?",
        'buttons': [
            'Yes',
            'No'
        ]
    })
        // Dialog returns a promise so let's handle it correctly
        .then((result) => {
            // Bail if the user pressed "No" or escaped (ESC) from the dialog box
            if (result.response !== 0) { return; }

            // Testing.
            if (result.response === 0) {
                console.log('The "Yes" button was pressed (main process)');
            }

            // Reply to the render process
            window.webContents.send('dialogResponse', result.response);
        })
})
```

---

For proper communication between processes, we must
use [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From render to main
        openDialog: () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('openDialog');
        },
        dialogResponse: (response) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('dialogResponse', response);
        }
    }
);
```

---

Finally, your `index.html` file will listen for a button click. Once clicked, send a message to the main process to open
the
dialog box.

Once a valid response is received from the dialog box, the response is sent back to the render process for processing.

> PS: The render
> method [`ipcRenderer.invoke()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)
> could be used instead of
> the [`ipcRenderer.send()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args) method.
> But if it was, you would need to handle the "No" or escape (ESC) response in the render process.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="openDialog" value="Show Dialog">

        <hr>

        <div id="response"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        // Open dialog (in main process) when "Show Dialog" button is clicked
        document.getElementById('openDialog').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRenderer.openDialog('openDialog');
        })

        // Response from main process
        window.ipcRenderer.dialogResponse((event, response) => {
            if (response === 0) {
                // Perform your render action here
                document.getElementById('response').innerText = 'The "Yes" button was clicked';
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

---

To use more than 2 buttons in your dialog box(es), in the creation of your dialog box you may want to designate
a `cancelId` and check for all valid return values before actioning anything.